# How do I make an if statement that check if a part has been clicked (roblox lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

How do I make an if statement check if a part has been clicked on?
Also it's not a gui
Here is some of the code I wrote:

```
local chat = game.Workspace.Dummy1.Head.Dialog
local Menu = {"pizza","fries","hamburger"}

local Item = math.random(1,#Menu)  -- chooses random Item from the table

chat.InitialPrompt = (Menu[Item]) -- says random item

local PizzaButton = game.Workspace.PizzaButton -- a variable for the button
local FriesButton = game.Workspace.FriesButton -- a variable for the button
local BurgerButton = game.Workspace.BurgerButton -- a variable for the button

if chat.InitialPrompt == "pizza" then -- checks what have random item has been chosen
    print("Pizza has been chosen")
    if  -- Here I want to check if a button has been clicked
elseif chat.InitialPrompt == "fries" then -- checks what have random item has been chosen
    print("Fries has been chosen")
    if -- Here I want to check if a button has been clicked
elseif chat.InitialPrompt == "hamburger" then -- checks what have random item has been chosen
    print("Burger has been chosen")
    if -- Here I want to check if a button has been clicked
else
    print("Error")
end
```

This is the best I could explain it

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, you can add a bool value inside the button parts and name it **clicked**. And set the value to true when the button is first clicked.

```lua
    if chat.InitialPrompt == "pizza" then -- checks what have random item has been chosen
        print("Pizza has been chosen")
        -- code inserted here
        if PizzaButton.clicked.Value == true then
            -- The Button is already clicked
        else
            PizzaButton.clicked.Value = true
            -- Actions to take on first click
        end
    elseif --do the same for all other buttons
```

Answer (score 0):

With what the guy above me said you should also add this to reduce the lines of code

```
local chat = game.Workspace.Dummy1.Head.Dialog
local Menu = {"Pizza","Fries","Hamburger"}

local Item = math.random(1,#Menu)

chat.InitialPrompt = (Menu[Item])

local PizzaButton = game.Workspace.PizzaButton
local FriesButton = game.Workspace.FriesButton
local BurgerButton = game.Workspace.BurgerButton

if table.find(Menu,chat.InitialPrompt) then
    print(chat.InitialPrompt.." has been chosen")
else
    print("Error")
end
```